# Twilight Zone (TOS) Visual Riddle #6

Tags: visual, rebus

Next riddle, wherein you guess the name of the actor or character suggested by the illustration.

[image: l]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Bill Mumy](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0612621/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t28), because you have a picture of a billy goat and person wrapped in bandages like a mummy.